# TypeError: Cannot read property "value" from undefined. (line 13, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am a newbie and my Google App Script stopped working and getting this error. Here is the line:

```
function onEditCustom(e) {

if (['TRUE', 'FALSE'].indexOf(e.value) === -1 || e.range.getColumn() !== 9 || e.range.getSheet().getName() !== SHEET_NAME) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: It appears this is an installed on edit trigger, not the simple trigger onEdit(e).  How are you capturing the error message?  Logger.log?

Comment: App script is sending me a type error. Here is the full code.

Comment: You can edit your original post to show the full code.

Comment: If you mean your are running from script editor that won't work because e is undefined.  e is the event object containing information about which cell the user edited.

Comment: The error means that one of your values, with a property key of `value` is undefined and is returning no element. Make sure that all elements exist in your index. Check this [link](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/issues/233) for reference.